# Using text in a column of Date/Time type in access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a column in MS Access in which the data could be any of the following:

- A date
- Text string: "n/a"
- Text string: "n/e"

The vast majority of entries will be dates but a very few will need to be these specified text strings. I would like to still be able to perform date calculations on the column. Whats the best datatype to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best approach would be to leave the date field as Date/Time and then add another field to indicate the status if the Date/Time field is Null. Something like:

```
DateField   DateStatus
---------   ----------
2014-09-21
            n/a
2014-09-23
2014-09-25
            n/e
```

You *could* use a single Text field, but then any time you wanted to use the field value as a proper Date/Time value you'd have to convert it using `CDate()`. You would also have the possibility of other junk getting in there, or dates getting entered in different formats (e.g. `d/m/yyyy` vs. `m/d/yyyy`). And finally, you would lose the ability to easily determine whether a Date/Time value is in a particular row (which in my approach would simply be `... WHERE DateField IS [NOT] NULL`).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gord Thompson's answer - mainly because it's so non-intuitive to have, essentially, two completely different [types of data](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) in a single column, and because it's going to make validation/[data integrity stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) so much harder with little upside - and, as he indicates with the `CDate()` reference, dates basically only work reliably like dates if they're in a "date/time" field.  Microsoft [has a page on choosing a data type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-data-types-and-field-sizes-mdb-HP005187521.aspx) that explains some of the Access-specific differences in more detail.

I also suggest that you don't actually have a *text* field for those "comments," since you say there's only a handful of potential options - use a Long Integer and connect back to a separate table with the list of allowable entries.  This will allow you to run reports more easily, change the "display text" in one step instead of potentially dozens of times, etc.  It also saves a relatively small amount of space per record (long integer = 4 bytes; text = up to 255 bytes.)

You can also do fun data/reporting stuff with that Comment (long integer) field and dates - even combined into ranges, by the way - queries let you use the two different columns to create a single answer.  I have a report that's grouped so that you can see stats for everything that's active (by quarter in which they start) plus everything that's pending (with the code indicating who's responsible for watching this record,) plus everything that's *not* pending but still doesn't have a start date (with the reason code displayed,) plus everything that's expired (by quarter in which they ended.)  It looks like each of those things is in a single column in the report, but it's actually like five columns that have been concatenated with the [IIf](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) function.

(Almost every argument I can come up with boils down to "[this is what relational databases are all about and why they're so awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).)